# Assigning values to bottom and top 5 percentile of numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

```
array([ 3.497  ,  3.0935 ,  3.3625 ,  3.56425,  3.497  ,  4.10225,
        2.75725,  3.766  ,  2.959  ,  3.9005 ])
```

In the numpy array above, I want to compute a new array where the bottom and top 5 percentile values are assigned a value of 100 and the others are assigned a value of 1. Is there a function similar to heaveside which can be used here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about calculating the 5 and 95 percentile with `np.percentile` firstly, compare the values in the array with the two thresholds with `np.searchsorted` which gives `1` if the values falls between and then create the array conditionally with `np.where`:

```
a = np.array([ 3.497  ,  3.0935 ,  3.3625 ,  3.56425,  3.497  ,  4.10225,
        2.75725,  3.766  ,  2.959  ,  3.9005 ])

np.where(np.searchsorted(np.percentile(a, [5, 95]), a) == 1, 1, 100)
# array([  1,   1,   1,   1,   1, 100, 100,   1,   1,   1])
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't use the `np.heavenside` function, so I'm not sure that it's what you're looking for, but it works:

`ret_arr = (99*np.logical_or((array<np.percentile(a,5)),(array>np.percentile(a,95))))+1`

It uses comparaison between the bottom and top 5 percentile, and then the fact that you can do mathematicals operations on a boleean array.

In this case:

```
In[73]: ret_arr
Out[73]: array([  1,   1,   1,   1,   1, 100, 100,   1,   1,   1])
```

Edit: Use or instead of and